# Pluriel de la forme locutoire « tout + adjectif + que + indicatif »

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques, adjectifs, pluriel, tout-tous

Dans la forme locutoire « **tout** *adjecitf* **que** *indicatif* » comme dans « Tout précieux qu’il soit », comment décline-t-on l’adjectif *tout* lorsque l’adjectif est au pluriel ?

Dit-on dans ce cas :

1. Tou**t** précieux qu’ils soient ;
2. Tou**s** précieux qu’ils soient,

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Tout](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tout/1)** est ici un adverbe invariable au masculin :

> **Tout** précieux qu’ils soient.

Mais qui s'accorde au féminin avant une consonne :

> **Toutes** blanches qu'elles soient.

> **Tout** éveillées qu'elles soient.